# How return the value every time in while loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus, canoe

i have the below code

```
import can

def abcd():
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel= '1', bustype='vector',app_name = 'python-can')
    MSG = bus.recv(0.5)
    while MSG is not None:
            MSG = bus.recv(1)
    return MSG

if __name__ == '__main__':
    abcd()
```

and i want to return MSG every time  how can i do ?
can some one help me?

Comment: Can you try to describe the behavior you want? I assume that the `bus.recv()` method returns the currently available data (one or more bytes). Do you want a result as soon as it is available, or after a certain amount of silence on the bus? And do you want all data (concatenated) or just the last byte? I think there are multiple problems with your code, but I need more information to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to consider turning your function into a generator, using the `yield` keyword instead of `return`. In this way, ending your cycle with `yield MSG`, your function will generate a sequence of messages, one per iteration in the cycle.

When your generator ends, thus `MSG` is `None`, a `StopIteration` exception will be raised, making the `for` loop terminate as expected.

Concluding, you can structure your code as follows:

```
def callee():
    while ...:
        elem = ...
        yield elem

def caller():
    for elem in callee():
        ...
```

Comment: it is coming only once and coming out  it didn't work

Comment: Can you please provide an example explaining your problem with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Elia Geretto you may need to convert it into generator function.Let me know will this changes help.

```
import can

def abcd():
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel= '1', bustype='vector',app_name = 'python-can')
    MSG = bus.recv(0.5)
    while MSG is not None:
        MSG = bus.recv(1)
        yield MSG

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for op in abcd():
        print(op)  # or you can use next() as well.
```

Comment: In place of print op i want return

Comment: You can collect all the yields into a list and do your processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you want, but I think one of the problems is that the `bus` object is created every time. You might try the following code. I cannot test it myself since I don't have a CAN bus available. I'm also not sure what the method should return. If you can improve the question, I can improve the answer too :-)

```
import can

def read_from_can(bus):
    msg = bus.recv(0.5)
    while msg is not None:
        msg = bus.recv(1)
    return msg


def main():
    # create bus interface only once
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel='1', bustype='vector', app_name='python-can')
    # then read (for example) 10 times from bus
    for i in range(10):
        result = read_from_can(bus)
        print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  # Tip: avoid putting your code here; use a method instead
```